# Unable to unzip files in EMR which are downloaded from windows SFTP server

Tags: bash, shell-script, zip

I am using below code to download the files from SFTP server & able to do it but I am facing problem when trying to unzip the downloaded files.

Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo yum -y install expect

cd /mnt/Additional_Backup/SFTP_Scripts/

################################ Unzipping file MDTR ################################
if [ "$1" = "ARG1" ]; then

rm RemoteFileList.txt
echo ''>  RemoteFileList.txt

expect -c "
spawn sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.com:/
expect \"Enter password:\"
send \"*********\n\"
expect \"sftp>\"
log_file -noappend RemoteFileList.txt
send \"ls -1t\n\"
expect \"sftp>\"
log_file
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"bye\n\"
interact
"

sed '1c\''' RemoteFileList.txt > text1.txt

head -n 2 text1.txt > arguments.txt


head -n 1 arguments.txt > arg1
tail -n 1 arguments.txt > arg2


read file1 < arg1
read file2 < arg2

rm -fv arg*
rm text1.txt
rm RemoteFileList.txt

cd /mnt/Additional_Backup/SFTP_Scripts/$1/

expect -c "
set timeout 1000
spawn sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.com
expect \"Enter password:\"
send \"********\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"cd /mnt/Additional_Backup/SFTP_Scripts/$1/\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"get $file1\r\"
expect {
  "*100%*" { }
  timeout { exit 2 }
}
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"get $file2\r\"
expect {
  "*100%*" { }
  timeout { exit 2 }
}
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"bye\r\"
expect eof
"
    echo "Unzipping ARG1 files in progress"

        unzip -o "$file1"
        unzip -o "$file2"


        echo 'All unzip done."
fi
```

But am getting below o/p when debug a script:

```
+ echo Unzipping MMIT files in progress
Unzipping MMIT files in progress
+ unzip -o $'MMITPARFeed2.0_06_01_2020.zip\r'
.ZIP.or MMITPARFeed2.0_06_01_2020.ziped2.0_06_01_2020.zip
+ unzip -o $'MMITDataFeed2.0_06_01_2020.zip\r'
.ZIP.or MMITDataFeed2.0_06_01_2020.ziped2.0_06_01_2020.zip
+ echo 'All unzip done. Deleting existing folders from HDFS.'
All unzip done.
```

When i manually running unzip command it works fine.

I think i am not geting exact value here as `+ unzip -o $'MMITDataFeed2.0_06_01_2020.zip\r'` to extract the file.

I have tried using `tar` as well as `jar` commands.

Can anybody help me resolving the same?

Thanks in Advance...!!!

Comment: I don't see an error in the output included in the question. Can you edit the question to explain in more detail what is going wrong here.

Comment: echo the value of $file1 in your script  to see if that has the expected contents. Can you tell what happens if you issue the unzip command from the command line?

Comment: It runs while doing it from command line. & echo $file1 gives me .zip filename.